# How to target a line in a lit via CSS

Tags: css

My ordered list line in CSS goes on to two lines.

I wish to indent the second line by 50px

I have tried this HTML

```
<ol class="infirmity">
<li class="birthplace">&ldquo;Totally <span class="bitmorespace">Blind&#44;&rdquo;</span></li>
```

with this CSS

```
.birthplace li span .bitmorespace {margin-left:50px; }
```

or

```
.bitmorespace {margin-left:50px; }
```

but it doesn't budge.

The firefox validator shows that the item is being read but not acted upon

Is the syntax right and I have something else wrong or am I misunderstanding how to target a line in a list

Comment: `.birthplace li span .bitmorespace {margin-left:50px; }` doesn't work because it needs to be `span.bitmorespace` instead. but `.bitmorespace {margin-left:50px; }` works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygbxGO

Comment: Thanks you. I guess it's something else then in the CSS!

Comment: Here is the full HTML of the table Cell

Comment: you didn't include anything

Comment: <td rowspan="3"><span class="tinyblock">If any person<span>included in this</span><span>Schedule is&#58;&mdash;</span></span>
               <ol class="infirmity">
      <li class="birthplace">&ldquo;Totally Deaf&#44;&rdquo; or &ldquo;Deaf and Dumb&rdquo; </li>
      <li class="birthplace">&ldquo;Totally <span class="bitmorespace">Blind&#44;&rdquo;</span></li>

Comment: .infirmity {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 110px;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: section;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
}

.infirmity  li span {display:block; margin-left:10px;}
 
.birthplace li span.bitmorespace {margin-left:50px; }
.bitmorespace {margin-left:50px; }
.infirmity  li.birthplace {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px; /* same length as the text-indent */
    text-indent: -20px;
    white-space: normal;
}

Comment: .infirmity  li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "("counter(section)")";
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.infirmity + p {
    margin: 1em auto 0;
    max-width: 190px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: small;
}

Comment: That works, too. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygbRBa `.bitmorespace` has `margin-left: 10px;` due to the selector `.infirmity li span`. If you're expecting it to have `margin-left: 50px;` because of `.bitmorespace` then read up on CSS specificity.

Comment: Thanks at least I know where to start from

Comment: Well I did read up on CSS specificity. In fact I have two books here at home at well, but still couldn't crack it. I guess I'll have to stick with a couple of nbsp;s or important